# Interaction trigger doesn't fire command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, command

I have an issue with the `Loaded` event of the window, so I am using NuGet package
[image]

I did everything required to use the package from this link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/open-sourcing-xaml-behaviors-for-wpf/

My xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDynamicWindow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDynamicWindow" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel}"        
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="UserWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Background="Bisque"   

    >

<b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <b:InvokeCommandAction
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ButtonsListBox, Path=Items.Count}"
            Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}"/>
    </b:EventTrigger>
</b:Interaction.Triggers>
```

`Window`'s `DataContext` is MainViewModel class:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly string path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\LogInModels.xml";
    public ObservableCollection<LinkModel> linkModels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<LinkModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<LogInModel> LogInModels { get; set; }
    public ICommand LoadDataCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddLinkCommand { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.LoadDataCommand = new CommandInterface(LoadData, CanLoadData);
        this.AddLinkCommand = new CommandInterface(AddLink, CanAddLink);
    }


    #region LoadDataMethods
    public void LoadData(object parameter)
    {
        SaveOrGetData saveOrGet = new SaveOrGetData(path);
        LogInModels = saveOrGet.GetData();

        for(int i = 0; i < LogInModels.Count; i++)
        {
            LinkModel lm = new LinkModel(parameter);
            linkModels.Add(lm);
        }
    }

    public bool CanLoadData(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

}

As you can see in the MainViewModel constructor LoadDataCommand should fire LoadData() method, but I put a breakpoint on that line, and when the `Window` is loaded nothing happens. I don't get any error, it just simply doesn't work. I am new to this concept so I don't know what is going wrong. I think I am using InteractionTriggers in the wrong way but can't find anything that would help to use it in a proper way.

**CommandInterface class is just class that implements `ICommand`**

```
class CommandInterface : ICommand
{
    Action<object> executeMethod;
    Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod;

    public CommandInterface(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        executeMethod(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


}
```

Comment: You should post your `CommandInterface` implementation if you want anyone to be able to point out your mistake.

Comment: @mm8 So, now I added my implementation. Can you guide me to links that would explain to me the differences between ICommand implementations and which implementation I should use in my app?

Comment: I can't reprodude your issue. The command should get executed.

Comment: You mean everything is okay with command implementation ?

Comment: The code you have posted seems okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel}"` this doesn't work for Loaded event, so after I set `DataContext` of View to MainViewModel instance in code behind(after InitializeComponents) it worked. If it doesn't work just change ICommand implementation to one that is in the answer of this question: [How to use the CanExecute Method from ICommand on WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002300/how-to-use-the-canexecute-method-from-icommand-on-wpf)